# Macro that adds a sum after inserting a row to a relative position

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie with excel. It took me days to figure out how to create a button macro that inserts a new row relative to the position of the button. I can currently do this with my macro. However, what I want to do is in that new row that was just created, to pre-populate a sum formula. Please see screenshot for better clarification. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3x7x.jpg

In this specific case, it would create an sum formula in cell C10 of =sum(E10:G10) but I don't want it to specifically go to those points, I need it all to be relative. Can you please help me, I am a complete excel macro noob.

Here is my insert macro:

```
Sub INSERT_NEW_ROW()
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but would be really cool if it is.

Comment: Do you need to sum *exactly* the 3 rows above? or will the number of rows vary?

Comment: it will be summing the column numbers in E10 -> G10, which will be user generated.  The macro's purpose is to create a new row and prepopulate an sum.  So the user would just have to type in the data for E10, F10, G10 and it would auto sum this in C10. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos for you to figuring it out this far on your own. Good work! My gut reaction is to use an offset from your button, which it looks like you're using for your relative reference:

```
Sub INSERT_NEW_ROW()
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-1,1).Formula = "=SUM(E" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 & ":G" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 &")"
End Sub
```

There are ways to make this more dynamic, but as long as your worksheet has the same format every time, this should work.

What this does is set the top left cell of the area your button covers as a range. Then it fills in a formula in the row above (the -1 in the Offset) and one column to the right (the 1 in the Offset). Since the button is one row greater in the sheet than the one we want to reference, you fill in the formula with `ActiveCell.Row - 1` to get the correct row.

Comment: Hi Tmoore, thanks for the help! When I tried adding your code in, I get a 424 run-time error, object required.  It doesn't like the Set rng line.

Comment: See if htose changes help out. I don't usually like to rely on active cells, but this worked when I tested it.

Comment: Np. let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Hi Tmoore, I have a new problem!  I am being asked to bring this excel sheet into google sheets, and sheets uses javascript!  I only know basic javascript, and I am completely lost on how to bring in something this custom into sheets.  You wouldn't happen to know javascript too would you? =)

Comment: I have a little JavaScript experience, but I've never worked with it in Google Sheets. I'm pretty swamped at the moment, but if I find some time I'll take a look. If you produce some code you'd like me to look over, post a new question and link to it here. I'd be surprised if you don't get a quick answer if you post it as a new question.